# Swift - Hide navigation bar shows in animation

Tags: swift, xcode

I am attempting to hide the navigation bar in the app. I did this with the following:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)

}
```

With this, I am hiding the bar at the top but when the transition is happening I can still see the bar for a split second then it disappears. Image below shows what I mean:

Screenshot showing top nav bar when transitioning from view to another

[image: Screenshot showing top nav bar when transitioning from view to another]

Comment: set `animated` to `false` on your viewWillDisappear

Comment: Did it @xTwisteDx Thank you.Post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method parameters change ‘animated: animated’ to ‘animated: false’